# How to provide an object asynchornously with Dagger?

Tags: android, dagger

I'm using Dagger1 and I have a list of Jokes. In my AwesomeJokeModule I provide a List. The list is provided by JokeDataLayer.getJokeCache(). The thing is, if the Cache isn't build up yet, the getJokeCache() method hits the DB getting a huge list of jokes. This could take a while, and while Injecting my Jokes into my Activity, this can cause a slow down since the Jokes are a member of my Activity. What's the best way to inject a member into something like an Activity asynchronously?

Some things I've thought of, was to return an empty list right away if the cache isn't built yet, and then somehow try to communicate that the cache has been updated? But it just feels like I'm circumventing Dagger/DI. Any advice or ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is where the `Lazy<T>` is for. Consider using LAZY INJECTION

```
class GridingCoffeeMaker {
  @Inject Lazy<Grinder> lazyGrinder;

  public void brew() {
    while (needsGrinding()) {
      // Grinder created once on first call to .get() and cached.
      lazyGrinder.get().grind();
    }
  }
}
```

This `lazyGrinder` object will only be initialized when you need to use it.

Comment: So I should be good to wrap lazyGrinder.get().grind() in a new Thread? My issue is that getJokeCache() takes LONG (depending on the amount of entries, sometimes it can take 2 or 3 seconds to return.

Comment: You can place the action of getJokeCache() inside doInBackground of an AsynTask to avoid freezing the application mainThread.

Comment: Don't I have to return something right away? Though? Do I return an empty List as my JokeCache? Would I also use Lazy in this case?